# C# I have three buttons each with the same loop but different string can I shorten it to one loop?

Tags: c#, refactoring

I have three buttons each with the same loop but different string can I shorten it to one loop so I don't have to keep reusing the loop?

```
public static string VarOutput { get; set; } 

async private void btnCourse1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string VarOutput = "";
    string[] names = new string[3] { "COP3488C,", "UWP1,", "This course is mobile app development." };

    for (int i = 0; i < names.Length; i++)
    {
        VarOutput = VarOutput + names[i] + "  ";
    }
    txtBoxCourse.Text = VarOutput;
    var dialog = new MessageDialog(VarOutput);
    await dialog.ShowAsync();
}
async private void btnCourse2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string VarOutput = "";
    string[] names = new string[3] { "DOP3488B,", "UWC1,", "This course is Cloud Computing." };

    for (int i = 0; i < names.Length; i++)
    {
        VarOutput = VarOutput + names[i] + "  ";
    }
    txtBoxCourse.Text = VarOutput;
    var dialog = new MessageDialog(VarOutput);
    await dialog.ShowAsync();
}

async private void btnCourse3_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string VarOutput = "";
    string[] names = new string[3] { "BOP3589,", "UWP2,", "This course Computer Programming Java 1." };

    for (int i = 0; i < names.Length; i++)
    {
        VarOutput = VarOutput + names[i] + "  ";
    }
    txtBoxCourse.Text = VarOutput;
    var dialog = new MessageDialog(VarOutput);
    await dialog.ShowAsync();
}
```

Comment: `can I shorten it to one loop` yes

Comment: Better yet just replace it with `string VarOutput = string.Join(" ", names);`

Answer (score 1):

Just create a method and call it with the proper parameters, like this:

```
async private void btnCourse1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string[] names = new string[3] { "COP3488C,", "UWP1,", "This course is mobile app development." };
    await WorkerAsync(names);
}
async private void btnCourse2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string[] names = new string[3] { "DOP3488B,", "UWC1,", "This course is Cloud Computing." };
    await WorkerAsync(names);
}

async private void btnCourse3_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

    string[] names = new string[3] { "BOP3589,", "UWP2,", "This course Computer Programming Java 1." };
    await WorkerAsync(names);

}
private async Task WorkerAsync(string[] names)
{
        string VarOutput = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < names.Length; i++)
        {
            VarOutput = VarOutput + names[i] + "  ";
        }
        txtBoxCourse.Text = VarOutput;
        var dialog = new MessageDialog(VarOutput);
        await dialog.ShowAsync();
}
```

**Note:** Code is not tested.

Comment: Your `Worker` method needs to be async and return `Task`. And the calls to it need to `await` it. (For that matter, it should be named `WorkerAsync`.)

Comment: @JoeWhite Just noticed the last line

Answer (score 1):

Refactor the repeated code to

```
private async Task displayCourseInfo(string[] names) {
    //Replaced for loop with this line;
    var message = String.Join(" ", names);

    txtBoxCourse.Text = message;
    var dialog = new MessageDialog(message);
    await dialog.ShowAsync();    
}
```

The for loop is simply constructing a string with spaces which can be replaced with a `String.Join`

Call the method in the event handlers.

```
private async void btnCourse1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    var names = new []{ "COP3488C,", "UWP1,", "This course is mobile app development." };
    await displayCourseInfo(names);
}

private async void btnCourse2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    var names = new []{ "DOP3488B,", "UWC1,", "This course is Cloud Computing." };
    await displayCourseInfo(names);
}

private async void btnCourse3_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {    
    var names = new []{ "BOP3589,", "UWP2,", "This course Computer Programming Java 1." };
    await displayCourseInfo(names);    
}
```

Comment: Upvote for removing unnecessary loop, downvote for changing the final message

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Settle down on those arbitrary downvotes for, at the worst, what amounts to trifles. If the concept is relayed then the answer is correct despite it not following strict style guidelines. A simple comment will suffice. Downvotes should be used for outright incorrect answers or site rules violations.

Comment: I like the .Join method. That is very nicely implemented.

Comment: @gmiley not sure where you saw the downvote, I just didn't vote at all. And the answer is incorrect, it changes the final message presented to the user

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Well, on my answer to this question it was immediately downvoted at the same time you responded citing stylistic differences that had absolutely **no** bearing on the correctness of my answer. I decided to just delete my answer rather than deal with it, but then I saw you post a comment describing the same activity on this post, so I figured I would at the very least mention it. Maybe it was coincidence, I find though that is rarely the case.

Comment: @gmiley That was a coincidence, I rather wait for you to update/comment rather than straight downvote :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe by adding an extension method to the string class you may clarify the code and then doing some basic refactoring. This is one way to do it.

```
namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    public static class myExtensionMethods
    {
        public static string GetSubs(this string[] input)
        {
            string value = "";
            input.Select(sub => value += $"{sub} ");
            return value;
        }
    }
    class Program
    {        

        async private void btnCourse1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            await ShowDialogAsync(new string[] { "COP3488C,", "UWP1,", "This course is mobile app development." });
        }

        async private void btnCourse2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            await ShowDialogAsync(new string[3] { "DOP3488B,", "UWC1,", "This course is Cloud Computing." });
        }

        async private void btnCourse3_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            await ShowDialogAsync(new string[3] { "BOP3589,", "UWP2,", "This course Computer Programming Java 1." });
        }

        private async Task ShowDialogAsync(string [] myStringArray)
        {
            string VarOutput = myStringArray.GetSubs();
            txtBoxCourse.Text = VarOutput;
            var dialog = new MessageDialog(VarOutput);
            await dialog.ShowAsync();
        }
```